# Pattern for creating reuseable components

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm currently working on a long term web application Meteor. Where over time developers will come and go. So to ensure that the whole application retains the same look and feel I would like to be able to create standard components with meteor's templating system. So the feature templates should not contain any html whatsoever this should all be contained in the component templates.

I've tried `meteor-polymer` but it just crashes my application and it feels like I should be using the meteor templating system instead of adding another library. Also polymer depends heavily on the template tag that Meteor also depends on, so I'm not quite sure

Basically what I want to do in my templates is this:

```
<template name="someRandomFeature">
    {{#_RadioGroup name="dataInput" context=. formData=formData}}
        {{#_setLabel}}Test set{{/_setLabel}}
        {{#_addRow}}
            {{assignValues value="random"}}
            {{#_setCaption}}Random{/_setCaption}}
        {{/_addRow}}
        {{#_addRow}}
            {{assignValues value="expression"}}
            {{#_setCaption}}Expression: {{_TextInput name="testSetExpression" inline=true}}{{/_setCaption}}
        {{/_addRow}}
    {{/_RadioGroup}}

    {{#_FormGroup}}
        {{#_Config}}
            {{assignValues numRows=2}}
        {{/_Config}}

        {{#_setRow 0}}
            {{#_SetLabel}}Number of tests{{/_SetLabel}}
            {{#_setStageContent}}
                {{> _DropDown name="numberOfTests" items=numberOfTestsList formData=formData}}
            {{/_setStageContent}}
        {{/_setRow}}

        {{#_setRow 1}}
            {{#_SetLabel}}To email address{{/_SetLabel}}
            {{#_setStageContent}}
                {{> _TextInput name='respondentSelection' formData=formData}}
                <span class="help-block text-left">Send all test mails to this email adress</span>
            {{/_setStageContent}}
        {{/_setRow}}
    {{/_FormGroup}}
</template>
```

Example of a component:

```
<template name="_FormGroup">
{{#with numRows=0 context=. formdata=formdata stage='config'}}
    {{#with execBlock UI.contentBlock}}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{#each getRows}}
                {{#unless ../disableLabels}}
                    <label class="control-label">
                        {{#with _constructStageList 1='rows' 2=_id 3='label'}}
                            {{> UI.contentBlock stage=this stageContext=../../context}}
                        {{/with}}
                    </label>
                {{/unless}}

                <div class="row{{#unless ../disableLabels}} controls{{/unless}}">
                    <div class="{{#if ../fullWidth}}col-md-16{{else}}col-md-8{{/if}}">
                        {{#with _constructStageList 1='rows' 2=_id 3='content'}}
                            {{> UI.contentBlock stage=this stageContext=../../context}}
                        {{/with}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/with}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

And this works but:

1. The components themselves are overly complicated, lots of context switching which makes comprehending the component a living hell
2. The pattern has broken with quite a few updates

So has anybody tried to do the same yet? And/or found a pattern that works for this?

Comment: A very good question indeed!

Comment: Have you considered using react?

Answer (score 0):

There’s a project in development to do precisely this: [UI Harness](http://www.uiharness.com/), from the creators of [Respond.ly](http://respond.ly/). It’s private at the moment though. You can learn about it from [Phil Cockfield’s talk at the July 2014 Devshop](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/18/meteor-devshop-sf-july-2014) ([YouTube link](http://youtu.be/jscINbvWoDg)). From the video of the talk, you should get some ideas on how to structure your own components if you don’t want to wait for UI Harness’ release.

Comment: The projects on github are open already its just the .com site thats closed off (https://github.com/Respondly/meteor-ui-harness)

But this solution although it looks promising is not quite what I'm looking for.